# CGGradient not working on UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I looked at a couple of links online to implement a colour gradient on my `UINavigationBar` in my app.

I made a category to `UINavigationBar` and called it `UINavigationBar+Gradient`. Here's the code for that :

```
#define MAIN_COLOR_COMPONENTS       { 0.153, 0.306, 0.553, 1.0, 0.122, 0.247, 0.482, 1.0 }
#define LIGHT_COLOR_COMPONENTS      { 0.478, 0.573, 0.725, 1.0, 0.216, 0.357, 0.584, 1.0 }

@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBar+Gradient)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGFloat locations[2] = { 0.0, 1.0 };
    CGColorSpaceRef myColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGFloat topComponents[8] = LIGHT_COLOR_COMPONENTS;
    CGGradientRef topGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(myColorspace, topComponents, locations, 2);
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, topGradient, CGPointMake(0, 0), CGPointMake(0,self.frame.size.height/2), 0);
    CGGradientRelease(topGradient);

    CGFloat botComponents[8] = MAIN_COLOR_COMPONENTS;
    CGGradientRef botGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(myColorspace, botComponents, locations, 2);
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, botGradient,
                                CGPointMake(0,self.frame.size.height/2), CGPointMake(0, self.frame.size.height), 0);
    CGGradientRelease(botGradient);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(myColorspace);


    // top Line
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1, 1, 1, 1.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.frame.size.width, 0);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    // bottom line
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0, 0, 0, 1.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, self.frame.size.height);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

However, I'm still getting the default grey navigation bar in the iOS simulator. Why ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you override `-drawRect:` with a category for `UINavigationBar`.
Check this question : [What happens if two ObjC categories override the same method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221972/what-happens-if-two-objc-categories-override-the-same-method)

> Two different categories implementing the same method for the same
>   class will result in undefined behavior.

You need to subclass `UINavigationBar` to implement your colour gradient.