# Two Objective-C categories share the same delegate methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, delegates, objective-c-category

I faced an issue which I hope could find a solution for it as the structure here is quite old and complicated.
I have a class X which has two categories;
ex,

```
@implementation X (category1)
```

and

```
@implementation X (category2)
```

And both of them share the same delegate functions. Now, when I call the delegate method I want to catch it on category2 instead of 1.
Is that possible as I cannot remove it from category 1?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens if two ObjC categories override the same method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221972/what-happens-if-two-objc-categories-override-the-same-method)

Comment: Thank you, I think I will add another method in the protocol to fix this.